# Powershell script to log in to another program

Tags: powershell

I have a general question regarding the possibilities of Powershell, which I am learning at the moment. As practice I wanted to create a simple script which automatically starts steam and logs me in. I got the following:

```
$steamExe = (Get-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\Valve\Steam\ -Name     SteamExe).SteamExe
Invoke-Item $steamExe
```

After this the steam window pops up and Im not sure how to continue. 
Can I reference and type into the input fields of the Username and Password?

Comment: `Steam.exe` support [command-line parameters](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Command_Line_Options#Command-line_parameters_3).

Comment: Also, keep in mind that PowerShell is not primarily a *UI automation* platform, like AutoHotkey or the likes. It's a platform to replace tightly coupled UI processes with programmatical ease-of-access if you will